# How can I test (integration-testing) with supertest a Node.js server with Passport JS using facebook/google... strategies with OAUTH2?

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, passport.js, supertest, nock

I have a Node Js application and I'm integration-testing my app with supertest/superagent + nockjs.

I have a problem, because I want to test my login rest apis using supertest to REPLY with a FAKE PROFILE RESPONSE + token for example for facebook/google/github and so on. (I'm not interested in LocalStrategy, because it' very simple)

How can I do that?

I'm trying with GitHub, and I wrote this code (not working) absolutely wrong, probably very stupid without any sense...It was an experiment XD.

```
nock('https://github.com/login/oauth')
.get('/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&scope=user%3Aemail&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
.reply(302,undefined,
        { 
            location : "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/github/callback?code=ab7f9823f03071209b26"
        }       
)
.get('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/github/callback?code=ab7f9823f03071209b26')
.reply(200, responseMocked);
```

PS: probably I made a mistake with url and status, I don't know.
Also, where I should set the connection.sid's cookie ?

How can I fix/rewrite this code to be able to integration-testing my application?

I'm also interested to use passportjs stub/mock, but I want a library supported and well documented.

UPDATE: I fixed the name of the mocked profile object (responseMocked)

Thank you,
Stefano.